# Change column names in Code-first Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these data classes:

```
public class X
{
    public int ID{ get; set; } 
    public string Value{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Y> Ys{ get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public int ID{ get; set; } 
    public string Value{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<X> Xs{ get; set; }
}
```

Suppose the tables generated are:

```
X [ ID, Value ]

Y [ ID, Value ]

XYs [ X_ID, Y_ID ]
```

I want to change X_ID to XID and Y_ID to YID but it gives me error:

```
Invalid column name 'X_ID'.
Invalid column name 'Y_ID'.
```

How can I change column names without running into this problem?

Comment: Either run an `Update-Database` command or update your edmx, depending on how you generate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing Code First Generation?  I would actually make the change to the variable name - and go and physically delete the database that was created rather than update if that is what you were trying and then re-create.  I have had similar problems when going the other way - i.e DB first.

Comment: It may not be the better solution of this problem. You can override OnModelCreating method simply.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue and my first attempt at resolving it was to edit the migration and update the column name there but sadly that resulted in an exception being thrown in the `Seed()` method. To resolve it I needed to modify my classes which using your example might look like:

```
public class X
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int YID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Y> Ys { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<X> Xs{ get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `class X` configuration class, something like:

```
class XConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<X>
{
    public XConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Ys)
            .WithMany(y => y.Xs)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.YID);
    }
}
```

Note I also tried an alternative approach that doesn't require adding the `public int YID` property to `class X`. For your example it would be similar to:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Y)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("YID"));
```

This was effectively performing the same edit I was doing manually on the migration and still resulted in an exception being thrown in the `Seed()` method, complaining that e.g. the column `Y_ID` doesn't exist. It was simpler to just add the `YID` property.